# JavaScript key holding down and release

Tags: javascript, html, button, esp8266, keyevent

I can control my bot through web. These are its url-

- **forward**-  https://172.0.0.1/forward
- **backward**- https://172.0.0.1/backward
- **left**-     https://172.0.0.1/left
- **right**-    https://172.0.0.1/right
- **stop**-     https://172.0.0.1/stop

I am using html button to do this.
But I want to control it with "arrow" key of keyboard.
My idea is if I press and hold **up arrow** key then the bot will go **forward**(https://172.0.0.1/forward) and if I release the **up arrow** key then the bot will **Stop**(https://172.0.0.1/stop) going.
and the same thing to

- backward - "down arrow"
- left- "left arrow"
- right-"right arrow"

I'm not familiar with JavaScript Can you please help me...

Comment: You should call your function "onkeydown" event, and stop the function when "onkeyup" triggers.

Comment: Hi, welcome on SO. Before asking questions here, you should try by yourself to find a solution, ask the internet, Google, or whatever, and then show here your research effort and tell why it did not work. For example, you could start by googling something like: "javascript action on key down".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this.

```
window.addEventListener('keydown',function(event){
if(event.keyCode===37) { //left
}
if(event.keyCode===38) { //up
}

if(event.keyCode===39) { //right
}
if(event.keyCode===40) { //down
}

});
```

***UPDATE***

```
window.addEventListener('keyup',function(event){
//    do something

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But where can I add key release function ?