# How to launch a function when an event stop?

Tags: javascript, html, events, canvas

Anyone knows how I cant check when an event stop?

Im coding a game just to learn how to use the canvas tag on HTML. To make player move, Im using switch case like this:

```
switch (event.code) {
case 'ArrowUp':
  // code
  break;
case 'ArrowDown':
  break;
case 'ArrowRight':
  // code
  break;
case 'ArrowLeft':
  // code
default:
  break;}
```

But I need to launch a function when the user stop to press the key.

Comment: keyup - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keyup_event

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript key holding down and release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64424372/javascript-key-holding-down-and-release)

Comment: @Matt I know how to launch an event when a arrow key was pressed, but I need to launch a function one single time when the user to stop to press the key. I try to put the function on defaul case, but is launched all the time

Comment: No, budy. But thanks for the comment

Comment: @JorgeDorio Create a `once` keyup event listener inside the keydown code ? or have a generic keyup listener that checks for some state that was set in the keydown code to control whether it runs or not.

Comment: @Matt a generic listener, run the same function regardless of the key that was stopped being pressed

Answer (score 1):

To do this I got use a event listener with the parameter "keyup"

```
document.body.addEventListener('keyup',()=>{
    // function
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
  console.log('clicked', event.code);
  switch (event.code) {
case 'ArrowUp':
  // code
  break;
case 'ArrowDown':
  break;
case 'ArrowRight':
  // code
  break;
case 'ArrowLeft':
  // code
default:
  break;}
})
document.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  console.log('key not pressed');
})
```

Comment: is almost this, but i need with keyboard inputs, like 'stop key pressed', but is running all the time